# Case_when executes code when condition is not met

Tags: r, dplyr

`Case_when` seems to execute code even when a condition is not met, see below:

```
df <- tibble(
    group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
    take_max = c(F, F, T, T),
    value = c(NA, NA, 2, 3)
)

df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(
        res = case_when(
            take_max ~ max(value, na.rm = T),
            TRUE ~ 1
            )
    )
```

`case_when` correctly calculates the value, but it also returns this warning:

```
Warning: Problem with `mutate()` input `res`.
ℹ no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
ℹ Input `res` is `case_when(take_max ~ max(value, na.rm = T), TRUE ~ 1)`.
ℹ The warning occurred in group 1: group = "A".
```

Why is `case_when` even calculating the max in the case of group 'A', when it should not be seeing the right side of the equation?

Comment: See the examples in the `?case_when` help page. There's a note that says "case_when() evaluates all RHS expressions, and then constructs its result by extracting the selected (via the LHS expressions) parts." The `case_when` doesn't conditionally evaluate expressions, it just conditionally returns different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically can't get away with not evaluating the right side in a grouping setting. This is a fundamental thing about R -- before it evaluates the expression `max(df$value, na.rm = TRUE)`, R has no way of knowing what to expect out of the expression.

There are two ways around this:

(1) Run the expression on individual groups instead of through `group_by` which runs all groups at once

(2) Make a simple wrapper function for `max`:

```
SafeMax <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NA_real_ else max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And use that instead of `max(., na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks -- I guess I have a lot more to understand about R's evaluation methods.

Comment: @JesseKerr maybe consider this. When evaluating for the `i`th row, we look at the first logical condition (i.e., `take_max[i]`). If it's `TRUE`, we look at either the `i`th value of the corresponding expression, `max(value, na.rm = TRUE)[i]`, or the first value, in the case that it's a scalar (and we recycle). The thing is, before evaluating, there's no way in general to know what that `i`th value of the expression might be.

Answer (score 2):

package `hablar` has an implementation of `SafeMax` mentioned in @MichaelChirico 's answer.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    res = case_when(
      take_max ~ as.numeric(hablar::max_(value)),
      TRUE ~ as.numeric(1)
    )
  ) %>% ungroup

#  group take_max value   res
#  <chr> <lgl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     FALSE       NA     1
#2 A     FALSE       NA     1
#3 B     TRUE         2     2
#4 C     TRUE         3     3
```